# SQLAlchemy order_by date edited and date created columns?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my articles model, I have a date_edited and date_created column, and I want to order by the newest of the two. Is there a way to do this using SQLAlchemy order_by? I would really like to avoid altering my model at this point.

Comment: How would `date_edited` precede `date_created`? Is it nullable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your schema looks like, but here's something that might put you on the right path to finding a solution:

Getting the newer of two dates, assuming your timestamps are stored as `Integer`s or `Float`s, is as simple as finding the larger of two numbers.

There's not a super straightforward way to get the bigger of two numbers like a math library function `MAX(x, y)` returning `x if x > y else y`, but you can mimic it with a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE 
   WHEN (table.date_edited > table.date_created) 
     THEN table.date_edited 
   ELSE table.date_created 
END
```

You can do this with a [case expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) in SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# [...]

myquery = myquery.order_by(
    db.case(
        [(Table.date_created > Table.date_edited, Table.date_created)], 
        else_=Table.date_edited
    )
)
```

---

To avoid this situation in the future, you might consider setting your `date_edited` column to automatically be updated to match your `date_created` column automatically upon creation (so long as `date_edited` is meant to keep track of the last edit, not if there was an edit at all), so you only have to worry about sorting by `date_edited`. (You could run a query, `UPDATE table SET date_edited=date_created WHERE date_edited=NULL;` to do this initially, and then make sure your code keeps this consistent in the future).